# AppSheet: I need FILTER the data and show each user the rows that contains his NAME

Tags: google-appsheet

I have this **Users** Sheet and the login process is working perfectly (if the user Email is contained in the Users list then the data will showup).

[image]

Now i need to show the user the data that contains his name only (Filter), from where i can do that ? and whats the code ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to implement the [Current User system](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Tips-Tricks/Current-User-Slice-How-to-conform-your-app-around-WHO-is-using/m-p/347947) in your app

- This will allow for all sorts of advanced functionalities

*FYI: you'll be better served searching for answers in the [official AppSheet Community](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AppSheet/ct-p/appsheet);  it's been around for years, with tons of really detailed posts (full of good follow-up questions and answers)*